# IEnumerable.Where missing objects

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, where-clause, equality

I have noticed a problem in my code where an `IEnumerable` seems not to contain all the elements I want it to, here is the code (it is inside a foreach which is where I get the `_Lis` from):

```
IEnumerable<Pot> result = pots.Where(e => SignArray(e.PotVal) == _Lis.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("Result count:" + result.Count());
Console.WriteLine(JObject.FromObject(new { test1 = SignArray(pots[0].PotVal) }));
Console.WriteLine(JObject.FromObject(new { test2 = _Lis.ToArray() }));
```

Result:

```
Result count: 0
{
  "test1": [
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    1.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    1.0,
    0.0
  ]
}
{
  "test2": [
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    1.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    1.0,
    0.0
  ]
}
```

Comment: _"seems not to contain all the elements I want it to"_ - what elements do you want it to contain? What is `SignArray()`?

Answer (score 5):

Your two arrays are not the same object. They *contain* the same objects. Use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) instead of the `operator ==`, which compares for reference equality (i.e. do the variables point to **the same** memory address?).

```
IEnumerable<Pot> result = pots.Where(e => SignArray(e.PotVal).SequenceEqual(_Lis.ToArray()));
```